# Table row not stretching to 100% width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hiding and showing a table row on click of an anchor, but when the `tr` is shown next time, it does not stretches to it's full length. Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LSh4M/18/)

**Note:** go to `View Differences` and click on `envVariable`

Here is my code

```
 var dummy1='<list>  <TagResult elementname="osname" subCategory="system" value1="Linux" value2="HP-US1000" isEqual="false"/>  <TagResult elementname="hostname" subCategory="system" value1="estilo" value2="benz" isEqual="false"/>  <TagResult elementname="release" subCategory="system" value1="2.6.18-128.el5" value2="B.11.23" isEqual="false"/><TagResult elementname="version" subCategory="system" value1="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)" value2="U" isEqual="false"/>  <TagResult elementname="machine" subCategory="system" value1="x86_64" value2="ia64 hp server rx2600" isEqual="false"/>  <TagResult elementname="bitmode" subCategory="system" value1="64" value2="64" isEqual="true"/>  <TagResult elementname="numberofcpu" subCategory="system" value1="4" value2="2" isEqual="false"/>  <TagResult elementname="cpuspeed" subCategory="system" value1=" 1862.890" value2="1400" isEqual="false"/>  <TagResult elementname="maxfilesperproc" subCategory="system" value1="32" value2=" 32" isEqual="true"/>  <TagResult elementname="maxthreadsperproc" subCategory="system" value1="2000000" value2="                    256  " isEqual="false"/><TagResult elementname="mempagesize" subCategory="system" value1="4096" value2="4096" isEqual="true"/><TagResult elementname="ssaname3webserviceserver" subCategory="product" value1="ssasvck&gt; Attempt 1 at server &apos;null:-1&apos;ssasvck&gt; Server&apos;null:-1&apos; is down" value2="ssasvck&gt; Attempt 1 at server &apos;null:-1&apos;ssasvck&gt; Server &apos;null:-1&apos; is down" isEqual="true"/><TagResult elementname="TERM" subCategory="envVariable" value1="xterm " value2="xterm" isEqual="true"/><TagResult elementname="JAVA_HOME" subCategory="envVariable" value1="/home/hqusers1/IIR_1152825121_estilo_9.0.1SP2_32 " isEqual="false"/><TagResult elementname="SSANUL" subCategory="envVariable" value1="/dev/null " value2="/dev/null" isEqual="true"/><TagResult elementname="SSA_LIHOST" subCategory="envVariable" value1="estilo:45682 " value2="benz:7660" isEqual="false"/><TagResult elementname="SSH_CLIENT" subCategory="envVariable" value1="10.65.6.131 4760 22 " value2="10.65.241.204 367222" isEqual="false"/></list>';

$('#compareForm input:radio').click(function() {
        populateCompare($(this).val());
  });

$('#compareTable a').live('click', function() {
var elementId=$(this).attr("id");
showHiddenTr(elementId);
});
function showHiddenTr(eid)
{
if($(".differentEnvironmentHiddentr").is(':visible'))
{
    $(".differentEnvironmentHiddentr").css({"display":"none"});
}
else
{
    $(".differentEnvironmentHiddentr").css({"display":"block"});
}       
}


function populateCompare(cmp)
{
var mytr = new Array();
var mytrs="";
var i=0;
var xml=dummy1;
$('#compareContent').empty();
$('#compareContent').html("<table width='100%'><tbody><tr><td align='center'>Compare details being loaded</td></tr><tr><td align='center'><img src='/csm/view/include/images/loading.gif' alt='Loading'/></td></tr></tbody></table>");
if(cmp=="all")
{

    $(xml).find('TagResult').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("isEqual")=="false")
        {
            mytr[i]='<tr class="regulartr">'+
            '<td class="different" align="left">'+$(this).attr("elementname")+'</td>'+
            '<td class="different" align="left">'+$(this).attr("value1")+'</td>'+
            '<td class="different" align="left">'+$(this).attr("value2")+'</td>'+
            '</tr>';
            mytrs+=mytr[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            mytr[i]='<tr class="regulartr">'+
            '<td class="nametd" align="left">'+$(this).attr("elementname")+'</td>'+
            '<td class="value1td" align="left">'+$(this).attr("value1")+'</td>'+
            '<td class="value2td" align="left">'+$(this).attr("value2")+'</td>'+
            '</tr>';
            mytrs+=mytr[i++];
        }

    });


    $('#compareContent').empty();
    $('<div>')
    .html('<table id="compareTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">'+
            '<thead><tr class="regulartr">'+
                '<th align="center">Name</th>'+
                '<th align="center">Config1</th>'+
                '<th align="center">Config2</th>'+
            '</tr></thead><tbody>'+mytrs

        +'</tbody></table>')
    .appendTo('#compareContent');

} 
if(cmp=="diff")
{
    var env=0;
    $(xml).find('TagResult').each(function(){

        if($(this).attr("isEqual")=="false")
        {
            if($(this).attr("subCategory")=="envVariable")
            {
                if(env==0)
                {
                    mytr[i]='<tr class="regulartr">'+
                    '<td class="different" align="left"><a id="showCmpEnvironment"><img  src="http://pslxcsm01:8080/informaticaCSM/zkau/web/zul/img/tree/close.png"/>'+$(this).attr("subCategory")+'</a></td>'+
                    '<td class="different" align="left"></td>'+
                    '<td class="different" align="left"></td>'+
                    '</tr>';
                    mytrs+=mytr[i++];
                    mytr[i]='<tr class="differentEnvironmentHiddentr">'+
                    '<td class="different" align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;'+$(this).attr("elementname")+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="different" align="left">'+$(this).attr("value1")+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="different" align="left">'+$(this).attr("value2")+'</td>'+
                    '</tr>';
                    mytrs+=mytr[i++];
                    env=1;
                }
                else
                {


                    mytr[i]='<tr class="differentEnvironmentHiddentr">'+
                    '<td class="different" align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;'+$(this).attr("elementname")+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="different" align="left">'+$(this).attr("value1")+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="different" align="left">'+$(this).attr("value2")+'</td>'+
                    '</tr>';
                    mytrs+=mytr[i++];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mytr[i]='<tr class="regulartr">'+
                '<td class="different" align="left">'+$(this).attr("elementname")+'</td>'+
                '<td class="different" align="left">'+$(this).attr("value1")+'</td>'+
                '<td class="different" align="left">'+$(this).attr("value2")+'</td>'+
                '</tr>';
                mytrs+=mytr[i++];
            }



        }


    });


    $('#compareContent').empty();
    $('<div>')
    .html('<table id="compareTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">'+
            '<thead><tr class="regulartr">'+
                '<th align="center">Name</th>'+
                '<th align="center">Config1</th>'+
                '<th align="center">Config2</th>'+
            '</tr></thead><tbody>'+mytrs

        +'</tbody></table>')
    .appendTo('#compareContent');

} 
}
```

Comment: i might be missing something here, but i checked the site, clicked on envVariable, the bottom rows are hidden, click it again and the rows are visible. Couldnt quite figure out your issue

Comment: Off topic a little, but in your CSS, you have `display:"block"` and `display:"none"`. You should remove the quotation marks. `display:block` and `display:none`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default value of a `tr`'s `display` property is `table-row` and not `block`. It should be toggling between `none` and `table-row` instead. See http://jsfiddle.net/aQPZk/

Comment: Or simply use `.show()` and `.hide()` and let jQuery worry about which display-value to use: http://jsfiddle.net/LSh4M/21/

Comment: @Gustav: Why does my 3 rows under `envVariable` shows onload, why does not it hide? It only hides after I click, what can i do to keep it hiding from beginning?

Comment: @Abhishek: This is due to what @patrick points out above: in your CSS, you have the `display` property quoted like so: `display:"none"`. Since browsers cannot interpret this, it is simply ignored. However, you want to remove `display:block` from `.regulartr` altogether since, as you have already noticed, table rows don't behave the way you want them to when displayed `block`. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with your `display` property.

Change:

`$(".differentEnvironmentHiddentr").css({"display":"block"});`

To:
        `$(".differentEnvironmentHiddentr").css({display:""});`

- The `TR` is not a `block` element - *by setting it as such, the browser is conforming to the proper box-model specs*
- You could set it to `table-row` as Gustav has suggested, but *the easiest way is not to set the display property at all using a blank string (shown above).  This would leave the browser to use its default settings/behavior.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, useful info +1. Also can you figure out why does my 3 rows under `envVariable` is not hidden on load? only after i click on the radio button, it hides